# How to get Last 10 records from OrmLite?

Tags: ormlite

With ormLite I can get all record with :

```
myDao.queryForAll();
```

How can I get only the first 10 records and not all records ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to use QueryBuilder and set the limit.  Here's the javadoc reference:
http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#limit%28java.lang.Long%29

This is give or take what the code will look like:

```
QueryBuilder<MyDataObject, String> builder = myDao.queryBuilder();
builder.limit(10);
builder.orderBy("columnName", true)  // true for ascending, false for descending
List<MyDataObject> list = myDao.query(builder.prepare());  // returns list of ten items
```